Elements of a quotient ring $R = (\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})[x]/(3x^2-1)$.
I am trying to solve the next problem:
Find elements of the the ring $R = (\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})[x]/(3x^2-1)$.
I tried finding an isomorphism between R and $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]/(x^2+1) \times (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x] / (3x^2-1)$, but I don't know how to proceed. Any hints on how could I see the isomorphism?
I reasoned that $p(x)$ has no solution in $R$, but that doesn't implie that it's irreducible. But, as $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})[x]$ is not an integral domain, it should be reducible, but that doesn't give me
I think the last approach doesn't get me anywhere, but I wonder if there's any method similar.

Hint: $,3x^2=1\Rightarrow 3,$ is a unit so $,3\cdot 2 = 0\Rightarrow 2=0;,$ explicitly: $, 2 = 6x^2 = 0.\ \ $

Or $,(\color{#c00}3,3x^2!-!1)=(1),\Rightarrow, (2\cdot\color{#c00}3,3x^2!-!1) = (2,3x^2!-!1) = (2,x^2!-!1),$ by Euclid's Lemma. $\ \ $

I am trying to understand it, but I don't get it. So this would mean that $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]/(3x^2-1)$, is like $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]/(-1)$, hence nothing?

Modding out by a unit (here $-1)$ yields the zero ring, so you can ignore that factor in the ring product. The above hints show other ways to reach the same result.

Could you explain why modding out by a unit yields the zero ring, please?

An ideal $I$ containing a unit $,u,$ contains its multiple $1,$ (by $uv=1)$ so $I$ also contains all multiples of $1$, i.e. everything, so modulo $I$ everthing is $\equiv 0;,$ explicitly: $,r \equiv u u^{-1} r \equiv 0,$ by $,u\equiv 0.\ \ $

I understand it now, thanks @BillDubuque.
